# Производительность после установки reCaptcha и её альтернативы

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, recaptcha

Как бывает - делаешь отличный сайт, разгоняешь на 95+ от pagespeed. Ставишь капчу и получаешь 75.
Я пробовал разные методы:

1. Добавлять капчу через создание `script` тега, который вставляется после загрузки страницы
2. Использовал `setTimeout`
3. Подгрузка капчи при `focus` на любом инпуте.

Все это звучит хорошо, но боты это обходят. Логично - им не нужен фронт и время для навигации по сайту.

И остаётся последний старый добрый вариант - написать элементарную математическую задачу. Что-то типа 3 + 5. Все это через `Math.random`.

Почему я спрашиваю? Этот вариант не очень хороший визуально и в эпоху ленивых людей так же не очень хорошо. Предлагать такое я бы стал только в случае 100%-й уверенности, что боты не пройдут такую проверку. Но, исходя из того, что таких проверок я не видел кучу лет, вот и думаю -  стоит ли? Будет эффект?

Есть ли какой-то производительный метод не дать ботам отправлять свой спам и при этом, максимально простой для пользователя?

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли какой-то производительный метод не дать ботам отправлять свой
> спам и при этом, максимально простой для пользователя?

Любые методы, не использующие капчи - таймаут, скрытое поле (honeypot), проверка js, nonce и тд.
В оф репо полно готовых плагинов с этими методами.

ЗЫ. А капча - зло. Против людей, но не против ботов - её не сложно обходить.